# Java error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Float

Tags: java, android

When compiling, I received this error:
`error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Float`
What does this error mean?  It appears that the default value for a decimal is a double.  If so, how do I define a float explicitly in Java?  In my Android app, I've tried:

`public Float myFloat = 20.0;` and it thinks it is a double.
`public Float myFloat = 20;` it thinks it is an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out you have to declare it with an `f` suffix like so:

`public Float myFloat = 20f;`

Comment: Float is an object, float is a primitive.

Comment: You can use 20.0f if you want, f distinguishes float from double in Java

Comment: Interesting how fast this "turned out". And you could also write an answer to this question and that all in less than a minute ...

Comment: @Tom I realized that googling the compilation error when I got it doesn't return any results, so I thought it would help someone.

Comment: @JBaczuk Amazing that since you've added this that google now shows  _About 378,000 results (0.63 seconds)_. Could please let us know the secret to getting such a high rate of hits so quickly after adding a question and answer in So.

Comment: It is generally ok to write a question and an answer to a problem which may also occur for other, but please don't write the answer like you just recently found the answer after asking the question. This looks always a bit strange, then the posting time says, that this happened in a few seconds.